# How to run "dotnet publish" with the runtime flag in a multi arch Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build, dotnet-publish, multiarch

I have a set of ASP.NET Core 6.0 services hosted on AWS ECS Fargate. Currently they are running on x64 but I want to experiment using the ARM architecture. Also, I want to produce multi-arch images because developers might need to pull those images locally for troubleshooting purposes.

Currently, my `publish` stage looks like the following

```
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-x64 --sc
```

Note the `-r linux-x64`.

So here is the question:

Assuming I'm using `buildx build` to build the image,

```
docker buildx build -f .\src\apps\API\Dockerfile -t api --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 .
```

How can I pass the proper architecture to the `dotnet publish` command?

Answer (score 2):

Buildx provides the argument TARGETARCH, you can try that.
So this argument gets the corresponding architecture when it's passed via the buildx command line.
For example:
Dockerfile

```
FROM build AS publish
ARG TARGETARCH 
RUN dotnet publish "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r $TARGETARCH --sc
```

So if you're building the image like `docker buildx build -f .\src\apps\API\Dockerfile -t api --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 .`
The TARGETARCH will get values amd64 and arm64

If you need to get your desired string you can extract the publish command into a separate bash script and use any conditional statement to get your desired values.
So something like, publish.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGETARCH=$1

if [ "$TARGETARCH" == "amd64" ]; then
    dotnet publish "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-x64 --sc
elif [ "$TARGETARCH" == "arm64" ]; then
    dotnet publish "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-arm64 --sc
fi
```

and the final Dockerfile would be like

```
FROM build AS publish
ARG TARGETARCH
COPY ./publish.sh /
RUN /publish.sh $TARGETARCH
```